# How to delete image in Firebase via URL/link?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I got the link of image that I store in firebase storage. By using the link I can access the image I want.

I found a method of deleting images in storage by its image name (example: "helloImage.jpg").

```
final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(imageFileName);

try{
  await firebaseStorageRef.delete();
} catch (e){
  return e.toString();
}
```

Is there any method to delete image in firebase storage by using the link instead of name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using    getReferenceFromUrl method in **StorageReference **.

we can delete it using the reference.

```
FirebaseStorage.instance
    .getReferenceFromUrl(imageUrl)
    .then((reference) => reference.delete())
    .catchError((e) => print(e));
```

Comment: "The method 'getReferenceFromUrl' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseStorage'. (Documentation)"